# Celebs and royals watch wedding to Jack Brooksbank

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Can you have a wedding to someone? I know you can wed someone or be wedded to someone, and you can have a wedding of a couple, but I am not sure about this.

*Wedding* is usually used as a noun, but I am wondering if they are trying to use it as a verbal noun here.

Note that I saw this on a link on the BBC news website so I can;t give a stable link to it. They appear to have used different grammar in the article itself.

Comment: Sometimes the grammar in journalism is a law unto itself, and BBC headlines can showcase that. Apparently journalistic writing is based on the idea that you lose readers on every word, so more important words come first. I guess the usage here is that there's a wedding and the bride is so important that everyone knows who she is so there's no need to say her name? [Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wedding+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwedding%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows rising usage of "wedding to".

Comment: Google Books claims 14,500 written instances of [*his wedding **to** the*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+wedding+to+the%22) *[princess / girl of his dreams / etc.]*, and at least the first four of them match your context. So yes, you can talk about *a / the wedding **to** someone*. And it being a newspaper headline, you can dispense with the article.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a peeve

Comment: I can't actually think of a better alternative than "wedding to".  "Marriage to" isn't quite right as a marriage is an ongoing thing, lasting years (one hopes), rather than a single event (like a wedding).   It makes sense, grammatically, I think, if the verb is "to wed" then "wedding to" is to "wed" as "joining" is to "join".

Comment: Yes, @Pam, I was aware that they go to extreme lengths to shorten headlines, but interesting point that they also try to get the most important bit to the front. And sorry, I did not mean to imply this was a heading - it was part of a heading. The heading started *Princess Eugenie:* but I only showed the clause that appeared relevant to my question.

Comment: Yes, @MaxWilliams, there is a distinction but *marriage* can be used in the same sense as *wedding*. For some reason *marriage to* sounds better to me than *wedding to* but I can't work out why.

Comment: No @FumbleFingers, this is not a peeve as I cannot see any good reason for not using this phrase. It just didn't sound right so I asked for opinions. As MaxWilliams points out, if you can say *joining to* you can say *wedding to*. Part of the problem is that *wedding* has become a noun in its own right, rather than simply being a verbal noun, so rules for verbal nouns can make things sound awkward.